# Double quotes not escaped in R

Tags: r

I need the to escape the double quotes in the following example and R returns :

```
xx<-"the road is 'rocky all \"the\" way'"
xx

[1] "the road is 'rocky all \"the\" way'"
```

The final string should contain both the single and the double quotes

```
the road is 'rocky all "the" way'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You already achieved it. It's just that `print()` escapes the quotes when displaying them :

```
R> xx <- "the road is 'rocky all \"the\" way'"
R> cat(xx)
the road is 'rocky all "the" way'
```

Comment: how to create a character vector of this xx?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem  The object `xx` is already a character vector:  
`> xx <- "the road is 'rocky all \"the\" way'"
> class(xx)
[1] "character"`

Comment: @ Robert this just print the double qoutes within the quotes. **how can i remove `\` so that i can get `"the road is rock  all "the" way'"` ?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem If you want double quotes only around "the" then use `xx2 <- "the road is rocky all \"the\" way"`. But if you want this entire last sentence within an additional set of double quotes then use `xx3 <- "\"the road is rocky all \"the\" way\""`.

Comment: @Robert Mar your reply is right. But i am just asking about how can i remove backslach produce by double qoutes in string? I want to get a string without **back slach( \ )** appear in it. It's looks like this : `the road is rocky all "the" way` How can i do this?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem Is this what you want?  `xx <- 'the road is rocky all "the" way'`  As explained by @juba, the backslashes will appear when using `print()`, so you'll want to use `cat()` instead.