# assign multi-line text containing quotes to a variable in r

Tags: r

in python I can assign a multi-line text to a variable using triple quotes like this:

```
s = '''  "hello world",
       'hello world again'  '''
```

It seems like it does not work in R this way. Does anyone how to do the same thing in R? Thanks a lot.

Comment: R doesn't have such a feature. It assumes "irregular" data isn't embedded in the script, but imported from a source/data file. Strings in R with embedded quotes must have them properly escaped.

Comment: Thank you! @MrFlick

Answer (score 1):

You actually can accomplish the same behaviour using only double/single quotes.

In console:

```
> s = 'hello world,
+      hello world again'
```

In script:

```
s = 'hello world,
     hello world again'
```

Comment: The problem is if there are both ' and '' in the text, I need to escape those.  I want to find a way to get around it.  Do you know how to do that? thanks a lot. @Carles Mitjans

Comment: You can escape quotes with ```\```. This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960126/double-quotes-not-escaped-in-r