# Dealing with double quotes in SQL select statement with sqlQuery in R

Tags: sql, r, netezza

I am using the sqlQuery function in R to send a query to my ODBC database (Netezza).

Within my SQL query I have sections where I need to define a substring to a particular data type e.g.

```
("NUMERIC"(SERVER.ADMIN.V_D_DATE.CAL_YR_MNTH_ID) <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("TIMESTAMP"(DATE('now(0)'::"VARCHAR")), 'YYYYMM'::"VARCHAR"), '999999'::"VARCHAR"))
```

I have tried changing the double quotes to single quotes and running the code directly in Netezza but it doesn't like this.

Is there a way to keep using double quotes in a select statement when using sqlQuery function in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
DBI::SQL("\"EXAMPLE\"")
#> <SQL> "EXAMPLE"
```

Comment: just to make sure I got this right, the code above should look as follows: ("\"NUMERIC\""(SERVER.ADMIN.V_D_DATE.CAL_YR_MNTH_ID) <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR("\"TIMESTAMP\""(DATE('now(0)'::"\"VARCHAR\"")), 'YYYYMM'::"\"VARCHAR\""), '999999'::"\"VARCHAR\""))

Comment: That doesn't look correct, you just need to put a single backslash before each quote you want escaped: `DBI::SQL("(\"NUMERIC\"(SERVER.ADMIN.V_D_DATE.CAL_YR_MNTH_ID) <= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(\"TIMESTAMP\"(DATE('now(0)'::\"VARCHAR\")), 'YYYYMM'::\"VARCHAR\"), '999999'::\"VARCHAR\"))")`

Comment: Thanks DiceboyT, I looked around for more details and the penny dropped when I came across this example :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960126/double-quotes-not-escaped-in-r