# How to set single quotes outside a string and inside should stay double quotes

Tags: r, database, paste

For a Exasol-DB-query I need a special schema to execute the query. The query should look like that:

```
  dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM schema."table" WHERE "id" >= 5000 and "id" < 10000' )
```

But there is a problem to paste the sting together:

```
paste('SELECT * FROM schema."table" WHERE "id" >= ',5000,' and "id" < ',10000, sep="")
"SELECT * FROM schema.\"table\" WHERE \"id\" >= 5000 and \"id\" < 10000"
```

Is there any possibility for a solution?

Comment: The backslashes are not part of the string. R just displays it that way so you know that the quote that follows them don't delimit the end of the string but are part of the string.  Try `cat(x, "\n")` where x is your string to see what the string actually looks like internally.  Also some databases allow the use of [...] in place of "..." .

Comment: Here is the answer:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598922/dealing-with-double-quotes-in-sql-select-statement-with-sqlquery-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598922/dealing-with-double-quotes-in-sql-select-statement-with-sqlquery-in-r)